# How to require an Ansible task to complete successfully on at least one host

Tags: ansible

Let us say that I have three **nodes** that I run commands on with an **Ansible script**.

I wish to have the task run on all three nodes, and have it succeed if it completes successfully on at least one node. If the task does not succeed on at least one node, the script should fail.

Using `ignore_errors: true` obviously makes the script complete even though no nodes completed successfully.

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You can implement it in the same way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39301292/2795592

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment by Konstantin Suvorov has the solution

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Maximum Failure Percentage](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#maximum-failure-percentage) feature :

```
- hosts: webservers
  max_fail_percentage: 99
```

In your particular use case, unless you have more than 100 hosts, 99% should guarantee you that at least one host succeeded.